# Catel + Fody/LoadAssembliesOnStartup + Fody/ModuleInit and order of loading modules

Tags: c#, catel, fody

I use Catel + Fody/LoadAssembliesOnStartup + Fody/ModuleInit. I would like to know, how can I specify the load order of modules?
I want to use the serviceLocator.RegisterTypeAndInstantiate for this I need to load modules in a specific order. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really tricky. In a perfect world, it shouldn't matter in what order the assemblies are loaded (you shouldn't be doing service instantiation in ModuleInit, keep the footprint as small as possible).

If you have a really valid reason (but please explain it), then we might consider fixing that in LoadAssembliesOnStartup so you can specify an order.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I solved my problem I just added serviceLocator.ResolveType in InitializeAfterCreatingShell()

Comment: That's even better (both the usage of Orchestra and lazy resolving of the types :-))

Comment: @Alex808 you should mark this as the correct answer